# DataBinding in Usercontrol

Tags: c#, user-controls, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I have a `ListView` with `UserControl`:

```
  <ListView x:Name="peopleListBox">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                            <UserControls:ItemTemplateControl />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

`UserControl`:

```
<UserControl
  ..........
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=control:MainViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <control:DataContextProxy x:Key="DataContextProxy" />
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="Click" Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource DataContextProxy}, Path=DataSource.OpenCommand}"/>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Binding doesn't work. I think there is the problem in `Binding` because when I put my `UserControl` outside my `ListView` the app works fine.